# rsync requires rsync-path when remote rsync is in path

Tags: rsync, path

I am quite confused as to why rsync requires --rsync-path flag even when remote rsync is in path.

Consider:

```
$ rsync -avze 'ssh -p 22' --delete public/ pmatos@domain.com:~/public_html
bash: /usr/local/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

then I tried adding --rsync-path

```
$ rsync -avze 'ssh -p 22' --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync  --delete public/ pmatos@domain.com:~/public_html
sending incremental file list
...
```

So, the first rsync was not successful because it was searching for rsync in /usr/local/bin but as soon as I pass the obvious path for rsync using --rsync-path, then it works.

Why is this? (this command line is the one issued by rake deploy in octopress)

Comment: Do you have any forced commands at the destination end? Anything in the .bashrc or .profile that might set a local environment variable?

Comment: `$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep PATH` returns nothing.

Comment: If you just ssh in yourself and run `which rsync` what do you get?

Comment: `$ ssh pmatos@domain.com which rsync` returns `/usr/bin/rsync`

Comment: Weird. Clutching at straws, now: Is perhaps your local rsync `alias`ed to `rsync --rsync-path` (or some other local wrapper)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My memory is now quite fuzzy on this but the reason this was happening was that I used GNU stow on rsync at some point and created some symlinks that confused `rsync`s location. This was sorted after much hair-pulling. I am now much lighter on hair but on the other hand I have a working `rsync`. That must be a win if you ask me.